# interactive graphics in ESS with manipulate package

Tags: r, rstudio, ess

Anyone know if its possible to use these `rs_` functions without RStudio?  I pulled this example from the coursera class Statistical Inference,

```
library(UsingR); data(galton)
library(manipulate)
myHist <- function(mu){
  hist(galton$child,col="blue",breaks=100)
  lines(c(mu, mu), c(0, 150),col="red",lwd=5)
  mse <- mean((galton$child - mu)^2)
  text(63, 150, paste("mu = ", mu))
  text(63, 140, paste("Imbalance = ", round(mse, 2)))
}
> manipulate(myHist(mu), mu = slider(62, 74, step = 0.5))
Error in FUN("rs_createUUID"[[1L]], ...) : no such symbol rs_createUUID
```

I didn't realize there were libraries that required RStudio. I'm wondering if there is an interface for between RStudio and ESS, or some way to make the above work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a go at cloning and making the packages under https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/tree/master/src/cpp work in a standalone (i.e. not wiht RStudio running) fashion. Those will require (at a minimum) the `Rcpp` package to be installed and *may* need `inline`, too (not 100% sure).

Check the license for those files since you may only be able to use those outside RStudio under certain limitations/constraints.